# How to re-use codepipeline to deploy different lambdas without replacing an existing lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I followed this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/ to set up cross account deployments of our lambdas using Cloudformation as my automation tool.

I'm using the pipeline in this repo: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-cross-account-pipeline/blob/master/ToolsAcct/code-pipeline.yaml ***(pipeline starts at line 207)*** and the pipeline in question is in the `ToolsAccount/` directory;

I am able to successfully deploy the first lambda; however, any subsequent deployment replaces the old lambda but I want to have `lambda_1` and `lambda_2` both present in the console not just the latest one.

To deploy the second lambda, out of all 6 steps from the tutorial, I rerun step 4 and 5 of the tutorial like below:

4.In the Tools account, which hosts AWS CodePipeline, execute this CloudFormation template. This creates a pipeline, but does not add permissions for the cross accounts `(Dev, Test, and Prod)`

```
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name sample-lambda-pipeline \
--template-file ToolsAcct/code-pipeline.yaml \
--parameter-overrides DevAccount=ENTER_DEV_ACCT TestAccount=ENTER_TEST_ACCT \
ProductionAccount=ENTER_PROD_ACCT CMKARN=FROM_1st_STEP \
S3Bucket=FROM_1st_STEP--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

5.In the Tools account, execute this CloudFormation template, which give access to the role created in step 4. This role will be assumed by AWS CodeBuild to decrypt artifacts in the S3 bucket. This is the same template that was used in step 1, but with different parameters.

```
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name pre-reqs \
--template-file ToolsAcct/pre-reqs.yaml \
--parameter-overrides CodeBuildCondition=true
```

After running both of these steps to deploy the second lambda, it successfully deploys it but replaces the other lambda that was already deployed earlier in the console. *

> *How can I keep the existing lambda while deploying new ones and
>   have all lambdas present in the console and not just the latest one*
>   that was deployed?

*
My guess would be that by rerunning step 4 and 5, I'm creating a changeset of the previously deployed lambda and thus it will keep replacing the old lambda in the console. 
If my guess is correct, then how can I re-use the same pipeline but deploy different lambdas with it without replacing the previously deployed lambdas?

> Is there an attribute of the cloudformation pipeline resource that I'm
>   missing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use a single pipeline to deploy multiple different independent services / projects. This will cause problems when you "switch" projects because the template won't contain resources from the other project and therefore CloudFormation will think these resources need to be removed.

You can either:

- Add all the lambda functions together in a single template
- Setup a separate pipeline per set of functions

Comment: Thanks for your response; the tutorial claimed that we could REUSE the same pipeline for different lambda deployments so now I'm a little confused. We are concerned about reaching the 200 stack limit per account if we duplicate the pipeline and have one per function or even set of functions since we have hundreds of lambdas in our organization. Is it not possible to reuse the same pipeline for different lambdas deployment? The Build stage calls out to another template.yaml that comes packaged with each lambda function so it knows how to deploy it so can we not re-use the same pipeline?

Comment: Switching projects as you put it just means switching lambda functions for us. So we're only using this pipeline for lambda functions only. Each one of our lambdas come packaged with a `SAM template` which the codepipeline BUILD step calls via `aws cloudformation package --template-file lambda-cloudformation.yaml --s3-bucket $S3Bucket --s3-prefix sample-lambda/codebuild --output-template-file samtemplate.yaml` so that cloudformation knows the other resources from switching to a new lambda. So wouldn't you agree that codepipeline/cloudformation would know of the new resources from `lambda_b`?

Comment: @pelican can you call out which part references reusing pipelines in that tutorial? If it's incorrect I'll have the tutorial updated. "Is it not possible to reuse the same pipeline for different lambdas deployment?" - you can deploy multiple functions in the same deployment, they just have to all be part of the same SAM template. "We are concerned about reaching the 200 stack limit per account " - I believe this can be raised on request. I don't recommend doing unnatural things to avoid limits.

Comment: Sure @TimB can you call out which part references reusing pipelines in that tutorial? The CONCLUSION in this link: aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/… says: AWS CodeBuild eliminates the need to duplicate the delivery pipeline. Doesn't that support my earlier point that we should be able to re-use this pipeline for multiple simultaneous deployments (SAM) or subsequent deployments (one at a time) without destroying earlier deployments when cloudformation creates the changesset and discard old deployments?

Comment: @pelican what the post means is that it avoids duplicating the pipeline into every account you want to deploy a single SAM project to. One option is to have multiple CodePipeline actions deploying multiple SAM applications in parallel to different CloudFormation stacks, but you can't have multiple SAM applications deploying to the same stack.